# Infinite Scrolling in Blazor, load items dynamically

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-7.0

Im building a Website with Blazor (.Net 7.0).
I would like to load items dynamically. For Example i load 15 items and when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page i would like to load new items.

I only saw some people fix this problem with Javascript. Is it possible to do this just with Blazor ?

Comment: [This link](https://www.meziantou.net/infinite-scrolling-in-blazor.htm) shows how to create an infinite scroll capability that will load data when you reach the end of the page

Comment: There's a standard Blazor component see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/virtualization?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: I face the same question and i already use Virtualize but i could not find any event or property from which i get the info if the last element of the ItemsSource is visible so that i can fetch more data from the backend.